# Writing a letter to the British Embassy in Manila

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I am a British citizen and I have invited my 2 sons and a daughter in law to visit the UK for 13 days to attend the wedding of my youngest son. But they have been denied a visa despite having included a letter of support that I will pay for their return tickets and accommodation here in the UK.

The reasons are due to financial and economic reasons. I am genuinely inviting them just to attend the wedding then they go back to the Philippines. Can I write a letter to the British Embassy in Manila to assure them that I’m responsible to send them back home after the duration of their intended visit?

What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to Travel StackExchange.  For UK visa refusals, we normally require a scanned copy of the refusal letter, with personal details removed, so that we can understand the exact reasons.  In the meantime, please read through [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) carefully, as I suspect it will help answer many of your questions.

Comment: Such assurances are meaningless because they carry no legal weight in the UK...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the OP never came back to post a copy of their refusal after being asked, which prevents us from answering properly